# Excluding tables using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have 100 tables in RDBMS but I want to import only 50 tables.

How to do this using Sqoop? I don’t want to use `—exclude` command.

Please let me know the process with example.

Comment: Why you do not want to use `-exclude` command?

Comment: If i need to exclude 50 tables then it is difficult to add manually 50 tables by using exclude command.. please let me know how to proceed it

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55252151/3227693), will it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in bash by listing all tables with Sqoop and after that importing only 50 of them:

```sh
JDBC_URL=<jdbc_url>
DBNAME=<database>
USERNAME=<username>
PASSWORD=<password>
DATA_COLLECTOR=<import_dir>

sqoop list-tables \
    --connect "$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD" \
| head -n 50 \
| xargs -I {} sqoop import \
    --connect "$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD" \
    --table "{}"  --target-dir "$DATA_COLLECTOR/{}"
```